# Python MySQL throwing Out of Range Value error, but SQL Statement works via MySQL console

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am writing some data to a MySQL database via python. The table is fine, the query is fine, but I keep getting the following error:

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1264: Out of range value for column 'myData' at row 1

When running my script in debug mode, I can see the _executed SQL query. If I copy/paste this SQL query into MySQL directly (via Sequel Pro in my case), the query runs fine with no edits at all.

Has anyone seen this type of issue before and is aware of how to fix it?